# onServiceConnected callback of the binded service is not called in TabHost

Tags: android, android-service, android-tabhost

I use a local `Service` that is bound to my all `activities` and when I start an `Activity` I get a `callback`:

```
@Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
}
```

but if I use a TabHost and if activity is being started the next way :

```
TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Spec");
intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
spec.setContent(intent);
```

onServiceConnected callback is neved called.

Why? How to resolve this case?

```
SUMMARY:

intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); // In this case callback is called


TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Spec");
intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
spec.setContent(intent); // In this case callback is not called
```

Comment: post some more code this is not enough for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a tab instead of `bindService(.....)` you have to use `getApplicationContext.bindService(.....)` in order for the `onServiceConnected` callback to be hit.